# Python - Dual infeasible error SVM Quadratic problem OSQP

Tags: python, quadratic-programming

I need to implement a SVM for a school projet.
But I'm facing a problem when I'm trying to solve a Quadratic problem in Python using the OSQP library.

The problem is [image: QP problem]

my constraints are:

```
alpha >= 0
matrix Y.transpose() * alpha = 0
```

The matrix is :

```
[[  2.   3.  -4.  -5.  -8.]
 [  3.   5.  -6.  -9. -12.]
 [ -4.  -6.   8.  10.  16.]
 [ -5.  -9.  10.  17.  20.]
 [ -8. -12.  16.  20.  32.]]
```

The below python code setup the problem and try to solve it but it failed with a dual infeasible error.

I have change multiple settings  like (iter, dual_infeasible error limit) but it's still failed

- q corresponds to the right  side of the problem (linear part)
- A is the constraint `( Y.transpose * alpha = 0)`
- l is lower bound
- u is upper bound

  P = sparse.csc_matrix(bigMatrix)
  q = np.array([-1, -1, -1, -1, -1])
  A = sparse.csc_matrix(np.transpose(Y))
  l = np.array([0])
  u = np.array([np.inf])

  prob = osqp.OSQP()
  prob.setup(P, q, A, l, u)
  res = prob.solve()

Do you have any suggestions to solve the problem.
Note : I'm not 100% sure the problem is correctly setup.

The results I should get from this problem is :

```
alpha1 1.11022 x10^16, alpha2 2.5, alpha3 2., alpha4 0.5, alpha5 1.4363*10^24
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example script. Without knowing matrix `P` it is hard to reproduce the problem. I suspect your lower/upper bounds are not correct. They are not directly the lower/upper bounds of the variables, but to the constraints. Check out the formulation at https://osqp.org/docs/. I suggest you to post the problem to the new [osqp Discourse forum](https://osqp.discourse.group/).